# Sort a 2D numpy array by the median value of the rows

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a 2D list in python, I can easily sort by the median value of each sublist like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1,2,3],[1,1,1],[3,3,3,]]
a.sort(key=lambda x: np.median(x))
print a
```

Yielding...

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Is there a way to do this with a numpy array without converting it to a regular python list?

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,1,1],[3,3,3,]])
a.sort(key=lambda x: np.median(x))
```

Comment: Aside: you can write `key=np.median` instead of `lambda x: np.median(x)`.  No need for the extra layer of indirection.

Comment: Good point! For some odd reason, that had not occurred to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the numpythonic way would be to use fancy-indexing:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,1,1],[3,3,3,]])
>>> a[np.median(a,axis=1).argsort()]
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```